# Can one convert an "Either" list to an "HList" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, say I have an [Either Int Bool], and I want to convert it to an HList....  so

```
[Left 1, Right False, Left 2]
```

would become

```
1 .*. False .*. 2 .*. HNil
```

(I actually think this is impossible, but would love to hear otherwise.... even writing the type for such a function seems impossible, although perhaps there is a way to do this that involves more than just writing a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert `[Either Int Bool]` to HList because it is a dynamic value, but an HList has a static type which depends on its value. Consider the following:

- `1 .*. False .*. 2 .*. HNil` has type `HCons 1 (HCons False (HCons 2 HNil))`
- `1 .*. HNil` has type `HCons 1 HNil`

Both of those values are possible results of your supposed conversion function, but they have different types.

The above is all because the information about what value the HList has must be available to the compiler to figure out its type. In your case you can only get this value in runtime, i.e. when the program is already compiled.

Comment: I suspected as much....  Doesn't this compile time limitation mean that HLists are pretty much tuples (plus an admittedly useful append function)?

Comment: Yes, by that property they are very similar. In fact, with the most primitive approach your HList can be encoded as `(1, (False, (2, ()))`. The power of HLists however is in the type-level (compile-time) programming. But the actual field of their application is very limited and seems to be more academic than practical. Studying Type Families might help a lot in understanding the purposes of HLists.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post by Oleg](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell@haskell.org/msg18908.html) on how to do extensible variants with HList.

Comment: I read the post, and found it interesting, although it doesn't deal with my question....  It is a description of what an HList is (they homebrew one rather than use Data.HList, but it is the same idea).  Did I miss something?  As Nikita points out, the type of a conversion function isn't even consistent, so this seems impossible.

Comment: The HList version on Hackage is the homebrew one, Oleg's the original :) . The post shows how to encode a sum type (aka variant, aka "such a thing as Either) in terms of HList, by implementing the left/right constructors as selector functions on the HList record representing a function you want to apply to your "Either". It doesn't *convert* as such, no.